# Does Three.js support more complex materials

Tags: three.js

I have a obj model with mtls of a cake I want to load to my webpage.
In Blend, the model I am using looks like this.
[image]

But in webpage it comes out as this.
[image]

I am using the Three.js OBJ and MTL loader to load the model, which works perfectly fine on less complex models. Now I am wondering if Three.js might not be able to display this complex materials.

```
newmtl Material
Ns 225.000000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.800000 0.800000 0.800000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 2
map_Kd C:\xampp\htdocs\uploads\Jakob\CAKECOLOR.png

newmtl Material.002
Ns 572.940236
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.031064 0.010178 0.002872
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl Material.003
Ns 900.000000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.023651 0.023651 0.023651
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 3

newmtl Material.004
Ns 900.000000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.057803 0.017225 0.006625
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 2

newmtl Material.005
Ns 900.000000
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 1.000000 0.878900 0.685513
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.450000
d 1.000000
illum 2
```

Comment: Is there a reason for exporting to OBJ/MTL? Using glTF will produce more consistent workflows. It's the recommended 3D format of `three.js`. (BTW: The path to the texture looks wrong. A web app can't load a file from an absolute directory path).

Comment: I used OBJ/MTL simply because the first tutorial I used to get into three.js used it aswell. I changed everything to glTF now.

Comment: One more thing. Do you know why my model with glTF looks vastly different than the model in Blender? Is it just the limitations of Three.js or did I do anything wrong exporting the file/setting the light etc.? Here are the examples https://imgur.com/a/CWzQEwA

Comment: Have you already tried to apply an environment map to `Scene.environment`? That should noticeably improve the lighting.

Comment: @Mugen87 Thanks for the tip. It looks so much better already. I am working through the material properties now for some fine tuning. Do you by chance have any recommendations?